# VMware Player missing kernel headers on openSUSE 42.2

Tags: opensuse, vmware

I use openSUSE 42.2 and installed VMware Player with the executable `.bundle`, but after that I get the well known

> kernel headers not found

error.

I searched the internet and did the following:

- install `kernel-source` for the availability of the kernel headers
- reboot
- reinstall vmware-player
- I went to `/lib/modules/` and created various symlinks

however I have no "/lib/modules/`uname -r`/build/include"-directory as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/a/592676)

How can I get `vmware-player` to work on openSUSE 42.2?

Comment: Could you please follow this [steps](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2053973) and show the output from point 5? thanks I'd add `--gtk` option to make it easier to read

Comment: https://pastebin.com/QS4rmUeR